# Why does my code say NameError: name 'self' is not defined'

Tags: python-3.x, nameerror

***Sorry if this is a really stupid question since I am terrible at python and most of my knowledge consists of the very restricted things you are taught before post 16 education.*** Basically I'm trying to do a coding project in preparation for when my classes start in September, and so far I've managed to get by teaching myself classes using online websites and people's online forum questions. However, I've come into a bit of a roadblock because my code keeps throwing an error. I've looked on websites and forums but they seem to be in very different situations compared to me and some of them just seem to tell me what I've done is right. The exact error given is: line 34, in returnBarbarianStats
    print(self.name,"the barbarian's stats:")
NameError: name 'self' is not defined

```
import random
def getName():
    syllables = ['en','da','fu','ka','re','toh','ko','noh','tuk','el','kar']
    firstName = (random.choice(syllables))
    secondName = (random.choice(syllables))
    thirdName = (random.choice(syllables))
    global generatedName
    generatedName = firstName+'-'+secondName+'-'+thirdName



# Classes-all creatures have names generated the same way and have the same amount of health.
# The way I have selected how each subclass will be randomly chosen is having the code select a random value
# from the list and depending on which is chosen it will give a subclass.
class preset():
    def _init_(self, creature, name, health=100):
        self.name = generatedName
        self.health = 100
        getName()
        self.name=generatedName


#Gives different attributes to each sub-class        
class barbarian(preset):
    def _init_(self, name, power=70, specialAttackPower=20, speed=50):
        preset._init_(self, creature, name, health=100)
        self.power = power
        self.specialAttackPower = specialAttackPower
        self.speed = speed
        self.name = name

    def returnBarbarianStats():
        print(self.name,"the barbarian's stats:")
        print("Health:",self.health)
        print("Power damage:",self.power)
        print("Special attack power damage:",self.specialAttackPower)
        print("Speed:",self.speed)

class elf(preset):
    def _init_(self, name, power=30, specialAttackPower=60, speed=10):
        preset._init_(self, creature, name, health=100)
        self.power = power
        self.specialAttackPower = specialAttackPower
        self.speed = speed

class wizard(preset):
    def _init_(self, name, power=50, specialAttackPower=70, speed=30):
        preset._init_(self, creature, name, health=100)
        self.power = power
        self.specialAttackPower = specialAttackPower
        self.speed = speed

class dragon(preset):
    def _init_(self, name, power=90, specialAttackPower=40, speed=50):
        preset._init_(self, creature, name, health=100)
        self.power = power
        self.specialAttackPower = specialAttackPower
        self.speed = speed

class knight(preset):
    def _init_(self, name, power=60, specialAttackPower=10, speed=60):
        preset._init_(self, creature, name, health=100)
        self.power = power
        self.specialAttackPower = specialAttackPower
        self.speed = speed

#10 randomly generated characters.
i = 0
army = []
while i < 10:
    creatures = ['barbarian','elf','wizard','dragon','knight']
    creatureType = (random.choice(creatures))
    if creatureType == 'barbarian':
        army.append(barbarian())
    elif creatureType == 'elf':
        army.append(elf())
    elif creatureType == 'wizard':
        army.append(wizard())
    elif creatureType == 'dragon':
        army.append(dragon())
    elif creatureType == 'knight':
        army.append(knight())
    i = i + 1

barbarian.returnBarbarianStats()
```

I've just given the whole code as I don't want to miss any important details out.

Comment: Hi, Welcome to python. There are lots of formatting issue with this code, such as we start  class name with a CAPS, var names etc. I suggest using a good IDE such as vscode with pylint, sonarlint etc which will point out code format issues

Answer (score 0):

you missed self in the parameters buddy :)

**[line 32]**

```
def returnBarbarianStats():
```

correct it to

```
def returnBarbarianStats(self):
```